# Problem with evaluating a single variable function using a vector argument in MATLAB

Tags: function, matlab, matrix

Let f be a function defined in the following way:

`f = @(x)( x + [x(1); 0])`

That is, the function f takes a column vector as input. Define yet another function g which uses the function f:

`g = @(x)(f([x;0]))`

The function g takes a scalar value as an input. Now I want to evaluate g with multiple arguments, say, x = 0, x = 1 and x = 2. Writing `g(0:2)` does not work: Dimensions of arrays being concatenated are not consistent. The result that I want is
`[g(0), g(1), g(2)]`. How could I do that?

Comment: You would either have to loop over the inputs or vectorize your functions. I would suggest ways to vectorize, but I suspect that the functions you posted are not representative of what you're actually trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `arrayfun` as basically a loop-in-disguise. You would have to set the named input `'UniformOutput' = false` (`'uni', 0` shown here), and your result would be a cell array with one array-element per input value

```
h = arrayfun( g, 0:2, 'uni', 0 );

h =   
1×3 cell array
    {2×1 double}    {2×1 double}    {2×1 double}
```

You could merge these into a single matrix using

```
h = [h{:}]

h =
     0     2     4
     0     0     0
```

Or you could define both `f` and `g` to handle row-vector inputs, given they only expand the number of rows you can do your computation per column in a vectorised way. Then the output is just a matrix with one column per input and you don't need `arrayfun`

```
f2 = @(x)( x + [x(1,:); zeros(1,size(x,2))])
g2 = @(x)(f2([x;zeros(1,size(x,2))]))
h2 = g2(0:2)

h2 =
     0     2     4
     0     0     0
```